# Could not convert string to float Exception

Tags: python, json, django

Recently I have been working on a code and got stuck for days on this error. Basically the program takes a students HTML Transcript and converts it into a table created using DJANGO. The program used to work with no problems but after recent school changes in the HTML Transcript file for students it keeps shooting out a error:

> Exception Value: "Could not convert string to float:C 
>   ExceptionLocation
>   C:\Users\CMPS\Desktop\AdvisementSystem\program\src\myproject\myproject\myapp\extractData.py
>   in splitTR, line 14

The course numbers for all Courses switched, for example,  CMPS190 has changed to CMPS190B and ENG201 is now ENG201B.

How can I tweak the code to read that "B" in with the course number? Code is below:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from CourseGrade import *

def splitTr(tr, grade):
    grade.department = tr.find_all('td')[0].text.lstrip()
    grade.course_num = tr.find_all('td')[1].text
    if tr.find_all('td')[2].text == "UG" or tr.find_all('td')[2].text == "GR":
        grade.course_title = tr.find_all('td')[3].text
        grade.grade = tr.find_all('td')[4].text.lstrip()
        grade.creditHour = int(float(tr.find_all('td')[5].text.lstrip()))
    else :
        grade.course_title = tr.find_all('td')[2].text
        grade.grade = tr.find_all('td')[3].text.lstrip()
        grade.creditHour = int(float(tr.find_all('td')[4].text.lstrip()))

def getDataList(student, fileName="Academic Transcript.html"):
    file = open(fileName,'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(file,"html.parser")

    studentName = soup.find("a", {"name":"Student Address"})
    if studentName != None:
        student.name = studentName.contents[0]
    else:
        studentName = soup.find("div","staticheaders").contents[0]
        student.name = studentName.split()[1]+ " " + studentName.split()[2]
    print(soup.find('td',attrs={'class':'dddefault','colspan':6}).contents[0])

    table = soup.find('table',attrs={'class':'datadisplaytable'})
    # print(table)
    # table_body = table.findAll('tbody')
    # print(table_body)
    trs = table.find_all('tr')
    count = 0
    term = ''
    department = ''
    course_title = ''
    grade = ''
    for tr in trs:
        if tr.find('span',attrs={'class':'fieldOrangetextbold'}):
            term = tr.span.text
            term = term.replace(":", "")
            term = term.replace("Term", "").lstrip()
            continue
        if tr.find('td',attrs={'class':'dddefault','colspan':4}) or tr.find('td',attrs={'class':'dddefault','colspan':5}):
            grade = CourseGrade()
            splitTr(tr, grade)
            grade.semester_completed = term
            appendValidData(student, grade) 
            count = count + 1

def appendValidData(student, grade):
    if grade.grade == 'A':
        student.gradeList.append(grade)
    if grade.grade == 'B':
        student.gradeList.append(grade)
    if grade.grade == 'C':
        student.gradeList.append(grade)
    if grade.grade == 'P':
        student.gradeList.append(grade)
    if grade.grade == 'TA':
        student.gradeList.append(grade)
    if grade.grade == 'TB':
        student.gradeList.append(grade)
    if grade.grade == 'TC':
        student.gradeList.append(grade)
    if grade.grade == 'TP':
        student.gradeList.append(grade)

def fillData(student,courseT):
    for grade in student.gradeList:
        gradeId = grade.department + grade.course_num
        if gradeId == courseT.courseId :
                courseT.grade = grade.grade
                if grade.semester_completed != "":
                    strList = grade.semester_completed.split(' ',3)
                    courseT.semester = strList[0]
                    if len(strList)>1:
                        courseT.year = strList[1]
                    else :
                        courseT.year = strList[0]
                    grade.isListed = True
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have to cast the course number as a float? The simplest thing I can think is to leave it a string, then BOOM no type conversion errors

Comment: Codes are often best stored as a string, as G.Anderson said. In Django, we always store our code with a `models.CharField`.

Comment: @G.Anderson which line of code are you suggesting that I leave as a string ?

Comment: If you leave the course code, `ENG201B` or `201B` as a string, no conversion issues

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're cramming to much code on one line. Here's the line that throws the error: `int(float(tr.find_all('td')[4].text.lstrip()))`. You're doing two conversions, one indexing, two method calls, and one attribute lookup. Try to avoid this as it's really hard to read and to debug. If you split them up, you'll be able to inspect each value in the debugger and identify the error.

The error says that you're trying to convert a string into a float (which is illegal if the string is not a number). This snippet `tr.find_all('td')[4].text.lstrip()` is a string which you wrap into a float. I don't know what you're trying to do, but there's the error. It could be that the index (`4`) isn't returning a number anymore, but a letter.

Comment: the index is now returning a number and a letter combined 190 is now 190B on transcript